# Is there a way to give an enchanted book with a random enchatment level?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So the backstory about this is that we are trying to give a reward out with of an enchanted book with a random level. Aka Protection I-V randomly. I know the command /give @p enchanted_book 1 0 {StoredEnchantments:[{id:34,lvl:X}]}, with X being the enchantment level, but is there a way to change that to a random number? Like random of the vanilla enchantments of course. Or do I need to explore scripts for that kind of stuff? Full story, Crazy Crates reward, of a random enchanted book, of a random level. Have the first two down easy, just the random level part.... Thank you ahead of time yall!

Comment: Maybe this could help, but replacing the team commands with give commands: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/325262/171580

Comment: Unfortanley dosen't :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a random number generator with command blocks in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/how-can-i-make-a-random-number-generator-with-command-blocks-in-minecraft)

Comment: Another good place to look is my rand() compilation: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376944/148546, specifically "command block source". Make a bunch of armor stands with a unique name, summon a block under a 'random' one using @r, and you get java.math.random() forwarded to you. Wire up pressure plates and redstone then use this as input variables to your command block (e.g. one pressure plate for each possible value) . Move from redstone to command-block using for example https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/fnlngz/get_redstone_power_level_and_store_it_in/.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't think you can, the closest thing to that would be different command blocks and changing them up every so often that way it randomizes, that or have them step on a pressure plate and the redstone signal going random directions, where the redstone sgnal would hit at different times, and when hitting one it ends up blocking the rest that way they don't get more than one, or use a dispenser....

Comment: Yeahhhh no. Commands is what we are looking for here to reward players

Comment: Then you can't unless you put a command for each type in the command in the blocks then let them guess then change it every so often that way they can't cheat the system

Comment: Yeahhhh, that's what it seems

Comment: ....yeah.......so you are creating a literal server or are you creating a map?

Comment: This is for a server. To give out a reward as a random enchanted book

Comment: Ok then since idk how servers exactly work then i have trouble helping you there, all ik about a server is that they're fun, idk how it all works, like how it's made and etc. I feel like the just use a ton of command blocks, but how they tp u to different areas w/ items? well, you got me there

Comment: U might be trying one of my suggestions, can't wait to try out your server... ;D

Comment: Just an idea, if it includes bosses then make one where the player enters the portal then the portal gets broken (by fire charges in a dispenser being activated by redstone, or lava touching the portal/flame part of it, (make sure to have a warning) so they either fight or  die....

Comment: Wait a second, is this crazycraft?